# How to use mget on files that don't have any common string ?

Tags: unix

I need to `mget` files that do not have any   common string :

`test1.txt`, `myfile.pdf`, `thiscase.pdf` etc

Currently I am using this

```
mget *txt*
```

and then

```
mget *pdf*
```

Is there any way to do all this in one step ? 
So how can I use the `OR` operator

```
mget *.txt* OR *pdf*
```

Comment: ftp clients are notoriously un-alike. But I've never seen one that required an `OR`. If `mget *.txt *pdf*` doesn't work, then you just have to issue multiple `mget`s per each group of files. Also, some `mget`s only support N number of files. I think I also ran into an `mget` that had a character line-length limit. If you're writing portable code, you'll need to create most of the feature in your own code. Good luck.

Comment: You might be able to match a regexp like (\.txt|\.pdf)$ or use a bash substring substitution.  Check the manual of your client.